# editor interface with views

Tags: views, blocks

I had a site where the developer set up an screen that you went to directly upon logging in. it was a custom view, within a template that displayed all the content. The view was a block and displayed only to editors.  I set this all up but the blocks are not displaying. Am I missing a step here

this is all i have in my page.tpl.php file

```
  <div id="content" class="clearfix">
    <?php print $content; ?>
  </div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your page.tpl.php there's nothing regarding regions ? You're certainly missing some code like:

```
<?php if ($page['sidebar_first']): ?>
  <div id="sidebar-first" class="sidebar">
    <?php print render($page['sidebar_first']); ?>
  </div>
<?php endif; ?>
```

See [page.tpl.php](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules--system--page.tpl.php/7) documentation.